# Format date in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

All,

I have a MYSQL table that has a column "DT_Created" defined with timestamp datatype. I would like to write a select query to retrieve the timestamp in the following fashion:

```
Sat, MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM CST

Lengthy Explanation:
Day, Month/Date/4 Digit Year Hours:Minutes:Seconds AM or PM TimeZone
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `DATE_FORMAT` command (see [the Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)).

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DT_Created, '%a, %c/%d/%Y %T %p') AS formatted FROM ...
```

The time zone is a bit more difficult... I'm not even sure in which timezone it will format the time.

Answer (score 1):

retrieve it by using a query as such:

```
$sql = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DT_Created) as timeToFormat FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

then you can format it with

```
$date = date("M/D/Y H:i:s",$row['timeToFormat']);
```